# Binary Loss Function

Tags: logistic, loss-functions

Currently I am working on Lasso Logistic Regression and in the book by Bulhmann et.al (2011) page 48, it is claimed that the binary loss classification function is given by,

$$ \rho(f,y) = log (1+exp(-(-2y-1)f)) $$

where $$ p(x) = (1+e^-2f)^-1$$

Anyone has managed to solve this because I am not able to solve it, I have tried substituting in

$$ y'log(p(x))+(1-y')log(1-p(x)))$$

where $$y'=(y+1)/2 $$

Comment: What is the relationship between p(x) and the rho-function. Also what does superscript - mean? Cant find the reference either by googling.

Comment: @JesperHybel the link for the (https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783642201912) for the above mentioned link. So p(x) is the binomial distribution and pho is the loss function for the negative log-likelihood.

Comment: Please note that you can (and should) use math ($\LaTeX$) markup on this site. Your question might have lingered unanswered partly because your formulas is difficult to read, [resources on using LaTeX on Cross Validated](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1605/155836).